# Azure: downloaded App Service source code but no project or solution file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, clone

I'm new to Azure and have been assigned to a pre-existing project, the previous provider is not very available for questions.

I want to replicate development environment on my local machine, so I accessed the server via FTP and downloaded `/site/wwwroot` directory.

I get some program files, templates, views, areas, web.config, etc. but not a project or solution file, so I don't really know how to open it in Visual Studio, should I just create a new solution and include all downloaded files in it?

Previous developer told me they used *devops* for source control and deployment, I'm usually a *git* user, can I somehow take advantage of *devops* (never used it before) or should start a new git repo and do source control on my own?

Thank you.

Comment: If they are using Azure Devops then, its same as traditional Git. Just get the clone URL from Azure Devops and do a git clone of the source code. Azure Devops internally used GIT.

Comment: Thanks, what about the missing solution/project file?

Comment: You need to get the ftp url and get the code. https://medium.com/@michaelhenderson/how-to-download-your-source-code-from-azure-app-service-59c848752b0f

Comment: In that tutorial, source code is downloaded from "repository" folder, which is empty in my App Service, so I downloaded from "wwwroot". Should I ask the previous provider the repository? Thanks

Comment: They have mentioned about FTP, did you follow that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did

Comment: I'll try via git and if the file is not there talk to the previous provider

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `@Ajay Managaon` for the comments.

- I have created a web application in my visual studio and deployed to app service in portal.

[image]

- Go to web app navigate to  **Deployment**<**Deployment Center.**

[image]

- Directly click on download where you can see the Zip file in your local.

[image]

- Add as new application in your IIS server check below.

[image]

- Follow below steps to browse in your local.

[image]

- Check here the browser is running fine.

[image]